# mongoDB connect (via Node.js driver) doesn't give me console log msg

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have this code on my server.js file.
I want to connect to this mongoDB data base and then get a console log indication.

However, there is no console log message for the database connection (for the server I do get log message). I don't get even an error message, just one message to the console log that the http is connected (nothing on the database).

why?
my code is below
thanks

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app); 
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var path = require('path');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');

 //more code that is not relevant



var url = 'mongodb://1.0.0.127:4444/small-talkz';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    console.log("Connected correctly to DB.");
    db.close();
});

http.listen((process.env.PORT || 3000), function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000 '+ __dirname);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the [docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html) of the Node.js driver, there is a default retry count of 5 and 5000 ms between each retry. So you have to wait a bit before you actually get an error in your callback. As you currently do not write the error to `console`, you won't see the error but get an error due to accessing `db` which is then `null`.

Change it to

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) { 
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Connected correctly to DB.");
        db.close();
    }
});
```

and wait for a minute and you will see the error. Alternatively, decrease  the retry count or the delay between each retry to see it faster failing :)

After you see the error you either will be able to see the reason and fix it (probably your URI is wrong) or at least you can provide us with more information.

Comment: tried that but still only get "listening on *:3000" printed to the log. even if I enter a wrong url I don't get error printed to the log

Comment: How long did you wait? As I noted it takes some time as the Node.js driver tries to reconnect a few times if you don't overwrite the connect options. I tried your exact code (with the code of my answer) and showed me an error after waiting some time. Besides that, you should double check your connection string as the IP of 'mongodb://1.0.0.127:4444/small-talkz' looks a bit strange to me

Comment: well youre right.. it did take a couple of seconds... how do I overwrite the connect options if I don't want to wait?

Comment: right again.
I wrote instead of local host <->http://127.0.0.1/
this bad url: 1.0.0.127

Answer (score 1):

Try with this to make connection. Run mongod with the default port 27017 & localhost.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/table_name", function(err, db) {
    if(err)
    {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      console.log("Connected correctly to DB.");
      db.close();
    }
  });
});
```

If its working with this, then make sure you are running mongo server on specific ip 1.0.0.127(weird ip) and on port 4444.

Comment: it is the same as above, you have just passed the url directly instead of passing through a variable.

Comment: @AjitejKaushik I know, I just want to ensure its connecting to default path and port. If happening need to check whether the issue is with the path or port.